# A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is already in the route collection. While I can't see it

Tags: asp.net, api, signalr

I'm using **SignalR** and a **Web API**, but I keep getting this error:

> An exception of type 'System.ArgumentException' occurred in
>   System.Web.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: A route named 'MS_attributerouteWebApi' is
>   already in the route collection. Route names must be unique.

Code **`App_Start > WebApiConfig.cs`**:

```
public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)
{
    // Web API configuration and services
    config.EnableCors();

    // Web API routes
    config.MapHttpAttributeRoutes();

    config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
        name: "DefaultApi",
        routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{action}"
    );
}
```

But I can't find it where I use it also. Does anyone know this problem and/or how to fix it?

Comment: Do you have this line in your Global.asax.cs file? `WebApiConfig.Register(GlobalConfiguration.Configuration)`

Comment: Comment out that line and try running again.